# Xtext Grammar mixins result in Guice injection error

Tags: parsing, guice, xtext, emf

I am writing an Xtext grammar that can access documentation that are declared before a functions.

Our current grammar defines `hidden(ML_COMMENT, SL_COMMENT,...)` with:

```
ML_COMMENT: '/*' -> '*/'
SL_COMMENT: '//' -> EOL
```

I have now created a second Xtext project, with the following grammar:

```
grammar my.DocumentationGrammar with my.OriginalGrammar hidden(WS, FUNCTION_BODY, EOL, SL_COMMENT)

import "http://www.originalGrammar.my"

generate documentationGrammar "http://www.documentationGrammar.my"

/* Parser rules */
TranslationUnit:
    eds+=DoxExternalDefinition*
;

DoxExternalDefinition:
    def = Definition
    | lib = CtrlLibUsage
    | comment=ML_COMMENT
;

FunctionDefinition:
    aml=AccessModifiersList ts=TypeSpecifier? f=Function '(' pl=ParameterTypeList? ')' /* cs=CompoundStatement */ // the compound statement is ignored
;

//terminal DOXYGEN_COMMENT: ML_COMMENT;
terminal FUNCTION_BODY: '{' -> '}';
```

I have created the dependency in the plugin and added this to the

```
bean = StandaloneSetup {
    scanClassPath = true
    platformUri = "${runtimeProject}/.."
    // The following two lines can be removed, if Xbase is not used.
    registerGeneratedEPackage = "org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.XbasePackage"
    registerGenModelFile = "platform:/resource/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/model/Xbase.genmodel"

    // we need to register the super genmodel
    registerGeneratedEPackage = "my.OriginalGrammar.OriginalGrammarPackage"
    registerGenModelFile = "platform:/resource/my.OriginalGrammar/model/generated/OriginalGrammar.genmodel"
}
```

Now in my third plugin project, I want to access this parser in a Standalone fashion. So I created the following Parser file (based on this example: http://davehofmann.de/blog/?p=101) :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IParseResult;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IParser;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.ParseException;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResourceSet;

import my.DocumentationGrammar.DocumentationGrammarStandaloneSetup;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class DoxygenParser {

    @Inject
    private IParser parser;
    private Injector injector;

    public DoxygenParser() {
        setupParser();
    }

    private void setupParser() {      
        injector = new DocumentationGrammarStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        injector.injectMembers(this);

    } 

    /**
     * Parses data provided by an input reader using Xtext and returns the root node of the resulting object tree.
     * @param reader Input reader
     * @return root object node
     * @throws IOException when errors occur during the parsing process
     */
    public EObject parse(Reader reader) throws IOException
    {
        IParseResult result = parser.parse(reader);
        if(result.hasSyntaxErrors())
        {
            throw new ParseException("Provided input contains syntax errors.");
        }
        return result.getRootASTElement();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I receive Guice Injection errors saying that

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
1) Error injecting constructor, org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a resource for 'classpath:/my/documentationGrammar/DocumentationGrammar.xtextbin'; a registered resource factory is needed
```

I know that the parser "should" be correct, since when I use the OriginalGrammarStandaloneSetup it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that your sublanguage also invokes the standalone setup of your super language. Usually this is generated in the `DocumentationGrammarStandaloneSetupGenerated` class, but please make sure that this was properly setup by Xtext. In the end, there should be something like

```
if (!Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().containsKey("xtextbin"))
  Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(
                "xtextbin", new BinaryGrammarResourceFactoryImpl());
```

in the callchain of your setup's `createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration` method.